# excel formula 3 criteria return multiple values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

I need to return a list of multiple values that match the criteria set. Right now I have the formula below to get values that match 3 criteria, which works well if I only need one result but now I need a summation/list of all the values that match these criteria.

```
=INDEX(Table1[[Helper column]:[Helper column]],MATCH(1,INDEX(($B5=Table1[[shelve]:[shelve]])*(D$3=Table1[[rack]:[rack]])*(30=Table1[[box]:[box]]),0,1),0))
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Have you got `TEXTJOIN()` available? If so, by the sounds of it, that would be worth looking into.

Comment: unfortunately I have to make it compatible with older versions of excel as well

Comment: That won't be possible then with a formula. You'd probably need to create your own UDF.

Comment: Would it be possible if I made it sort to different columns first? and then find where the results match?